# Eloquent destroy() isn't deleting row in db - Laravel 5.6

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am trying to make a feature on my site to delete a row in the database for news articles and it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my Route and my Controller:

Route:

```
    Route::get('/admin/news/delete/{id}', 'NewsController@destroy');

Controller:
public function destroy(News $id)
    {
        News::destroy($id);
        return redirect('/admin/news')->with('status', 'News successfully deleted.');
    }
```

It returns with the success message but the row never gets deleted in the database. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding), `$id` already contains a `News` instance (not an `id`).

You should probably rename it:

```php
Route::get('/admin/news/delete/{news}', 'NewsController@destroy');

public function destroy(News $news)
{
    $news->delete();
    return redirect('/admin/news')->with('status', 'News successfully deleted.');
}
```

Also, it's recommended to use `POST` requests when you delete data.